# Thermal equilibrium analogy

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, equilibrium

If a glass of water at 100°C is placed in contact with a glass of water at 0°C, ignoring room temperature, the ideal temperature of water in both glasses would be 50°C, right?
But since entropy causes energy to be lost when energy exchanges occur in an isolated system, can it be said that temperature at equilibrium wouldn't be 50°C, but ~48°C?

Please correct me in my aforementioned statements. Secondly, I'd like to find an analogy to compare high entropy and low entropy.

Given entropy is high when more energy is dissipated as unusable energy, meaning more work is done, the system of 100°C:0°C would do more work to transfer energy as compared to a system where the temperatures are 60°C:40°C? The ideal temperature at equilibrium are both 50°C, but is it correct to say that the temperature of the second system would be ~49°C, where heat is still lost, but less of it as compared to the earlier system?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should rephrase my question! I meant more unusable energy as friction and heat that's dissipated when energy is transferred in an isolated system. Is this correct?

Comment: Please desbribe specificslly what you mean by work done in this situation.

Comment: Where would the energy dissipate in an _isolated_ system?

Comment: @JMac Oh no! I must've gotten confused. I conflated the definition for second law of thermodynamics and my understanding of entropy releasing a portion of a system's energy as unusable such as friction or noise. How would I correctly combine these two then?

Comment: The entropy of the hot glass decreases and the entropy of the cold glass increases by more, even though the exact same amount of heat gets transferred from the hot glass to the cold glass.  Entropy is generated within the system during this irreversible process.

Comment: @yung-padawan Along with what Chester said, it's still easy to see what gets lost by entropy; even though temperature still averages out without loss.  To get the two glasses _back_ to the original temperature, it would require putting work in.  They do not want to spontaneously go back to $100° \ C$ and $0° \ C$ respectively; that requires an energy input.

Comment: Thank you both, I see the difference between entropy and energy a little clearer now. So getting both glasses to 50°C is *not* an irreversible process, and doesn't require work? Whereas getting them back to 100°C and 0°C respectively is where work is needed? Does that make this one an irreversible process, and by extension, how can it be correlated to the second law of thermodynamics?

Comment: Getting both glasses to 50C by bringing them into direct contact with one another **is** definitely an irreversible process.  Of course, it doesn't require or produce work.  In addition, it is possible to devise a process to bring both glasses to 50C reversibly, using ideal reservoirs.

Answer (score 1):

If

- the heat capacity of water is taken to be constant (for temp between 0 and 100°C) and
- the two waters contain the same amount of mass and
- assuming that the heat capacity of the glass vanishes

then the final temperature ist 50°C. Above all, energy is not lost or created, it just changes it's form: The energy stored in the two initial "water state" is the same as the energy stored in the final "water state". These two states differ in entropy, not energy.